# Why am I getting an undefined alert when entering a number into my array?

Tags: javascript, html, alert

When I input numbers into the array, I get two alerts: a `"number"` alert, and then an `"undefined"` alert. I don’t know how to fix this.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var myStuff = [];

function myfunctionA() {

  var enteredvalue = document.getElementById("numbers").value;

  alert(typeof Number(document.getElementById('numbers').value));
  if (enteredvalue == "") {
    alert("Input is not a number");

  } else if (isNaN(enteredvalue)) {
    alert('You need to enter a valid number!');
  }
  var elementExists = false;

  var x = document.getElementById('numbers').value;

  for (var i = 0; i < myStuff.length; i++) {
    if (myStuff[i] == Number(x)) {
      elementExists = true;
    }
  }

  if (elementExists != true) {
    myStuff.push(Number(enteredvalue));

    alert('Thank You for entering a valid number'. myStuff);
  } else {
    alert('Element is here');

  }
}

function myfunctionB() {
  window.alert(myStuff.length);
}

function myfunctionC() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myStuff.length; i++) {
    sum += myStuff[i];
  }
  alert(sum);
}

function myfunctionD() {
  if (myStuff.length == 0) {
    alert("already empty");
  } else {
    myStuff = [];
  }
  alert("Array Empty");

}

function myfunctionE() {
  alert(myStuff.join('\n')); {
    if (myStuff == [])

    {
      alert("Enter something into Array")
    }
  }
}


function bubbleSort() {

  var sorted = true;
  var temp;
  while (sorted) {
    sorted = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < myStuff.length - 1; i++) {
      if (myStuff[i] < myStuff[i + 1]) {
        temp = myStuff[i];
        myStuff[i] = myStuff[i + 1];
        myStuff[i + 1] = temp;
        sorted = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: alert('Thank You for entering a valid number'. myStuff); ? What are you trying to do in this line?

Comment: What is in the element with id=numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line evaluated to undefined:

```
alert('Thank You for entering a valid number'. myStuff);
```

Do you maybe mean?:

```
alert('Thank You for entering a valid number' + myStuff);
```

Comment: I kept searching, and finally realized I just needed to delete the ".myStuff".

Comment: Also, I am trying to get my toggle order to toggle back and forth (if that makes sense). I now have it to toggle descending, and want to be able to click the toggle and have it go back to ascending. Should I just copy the code and flip the greater than signs around on here?:                  function bubbleSort() {

var sorted = true;
var temp;
while(sorted) {
    sorted = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < myStuff.length-1; i++) {
        if(myStuff[i] < myStuff[i+1]) {
            temp = myStuff[i];
            myStuff[i] = myStuff[i+1];
            myStuff[i+1] = temp;
            sorted = true;

Comment: @Icantcode101 Do not post “thank you” comments. Do not post new questions in comments.